# Как сделать страницу ожидания ("Wait...")

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, уважаемые форумчане и программисты (веб)!
Беспокоит такой вопрос, а сам никак немогу дойти.

Вообщем нужно сделать страницу ожидания, самую простую с выводом текста "Подождите идет перенаправление...". Если бы все так просто. Я хочу чтобы эти точки "..." при их отсуствии добавлялись, а при достижении количества 3 ("...") начинались заново добавляться.
Пробывал своими мозгами решить, так ведь не получается, не доходит=)
Использовал setTimeout(), и if, т.е. 
Сделал 3 функции, а перед ними паставил d=0;
Вообщем код такой:

```
<scrpt>

d=0;          //это глобальная переменная чтобы могла влезть в функции

function funct1(){
d++;
document.write("Wait");
setTimeout('funct2()',1000);
}

function funct2(){
d++;
document.write("Wait.");
setTimeout('funct3',1000);
}

function funct3(){
d++;
document.write("Wait..");
setTimeout('funct4',1000);
}

function funct4(){
d++;
document.write("Wait...");

if(d==4){
d=0;
setTimeout('funct1()',500);
}

funct1();
</scrpt>
```

Заранее СПАСИБО Ребята! Знаю что поможете!
Хорошего дня и настроения! =)

Answer (score 3):

или [так](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/37bHN/):

```
(function () {
    var m = document.getElementById("message"),
        s = m.innerHTML,
        i = 0;
    setInterval(function () {
        m.innerHTML = s + Array(i++ % 5).join('.');
    }, 500);
})();
```

Comment: Классно с Array().join('.')! И удачно `innerHtml`.

Comment: Спасибо, но я еще не полностью разбираюсь в ЙС, поэтому мне надо простой пример=)

Answer (score 0):

`document.write()` не надо использовать, используйте innerText для какого-нить элемента на странице сделайте одну функцию, которая будет проверять переменную (например dots) на длину, если `>3` то превращать ее значение в '.', иначе `dots+='.';` в конце функции делайте 
`dotsTimeout=setTimeout(funct,1000);` когда надо перестать, просто вызовите `clearTimeout(dotsTimeout)`

```
(function() {
    var dots='.',dotsTimeout,
        out=getElementById('message');
    function showDots()
    {                 
      //тут тело функции, сделанное как я описал выше.
      out.textContent='Wait'+dots;
      dotsTimeout=setTimeout(showDots,1000);
    };

})();
```

Comment: а ещё это можно сделать на css :)

Comment: Спасибо! Не могу лайкнуть репутация непозволяет)) Спасибо!

Comment: @eicto хромиум 32 не умеет в такие свойства

Comment: `innerText` не работает в FF.

Comment: @Fike наверное у него всё ещё -webkit-

Answer (score 0):

Я бы [так](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/4nAqv/) сделал. Запоминал исходное сообщение. И к нему каждый раз приписывал подстроку от "..." длины 0, 1, 2 или 3 символа. А эти числа - остаток от деления на 4 инкрементируемого счетчика i.

IE любит `innerText`, а FF и другие предпочитают W3C-стандартный `textContent` ([не поддерживаемый](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t07) IE<9).

```
var tri = {
    speed: 800  // длительность одного "кадра" в 1/1000с
    ,d:document.getElementById( 'message')
    ,t:null
    ,i:0
    ,init: function(){
        this.t = this.d.innerText || this.d.textContent;
        setInterval( this.go, this.speed);
    }
    ,go:function(){
        var upd = tri.t + "...".substr( 0, ++tri.i % 4);
        tri.d.innerText ? tri.d.innerText( upd) : tri.d.textContent = upd;
    }
};
tri.init();
```

Comment: this.t = this.d.innerText || this.d.textContent;

Можно просто innerHTML - он универсальный. (только если кроме текста там ничего нет)

Comment: Я уже это заметил в ответе @Yura Ivanov.

Answer (score 0):

Можно чуть проще: http://jsfiddle.net/R6JFW/1/

Comment: Это какой-то костыль вы предложили, а не решение.

Изменил в div'е фразу с "wait" на "Ямщик, не гони", а она опять сбрасывается на "wait".

Что, в двух местах надо идентичный текст менять?

Comment: @sergiks спасибо, кэп.

Comment: СПАСИБО!!! НУ ТУТ БОЛЕЕ простое решение, хотя с библиотеками пока что не познакомился, но вижу работает! Спасибо!